# OpenGL: Easy way of stopping light at vertexes?

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex, lighting

I have a scene built in OpenGL. When my light is in the center of the room, the outside of the room is lit. Is there any easy way to make OpenGl stop the lighting at vertexes, or will it require complex calculations. Here are pictures of my crappy, quick scene showing the lighting as it is when asking this question: [image]

[image]

Comment: If you mean "make the sculpture in the middle cast a shadow", then no. Everything is rendered independently, without much knowledge of the rest of the things in the scene. You need to use techniques such as shadow casting or shadow volumes to do this.

Comment: For a room that will be seen from inside and outside, you generally want walls to have two planes, one for the interior and one for the exterior.

Comment: @slugonamission Yes and No, I don't want the walls to cast a shadow, so much as to have the part of the object outside not to be lit by the light inside.

Comment: @JonPurdy the walls are composed of more than 1 plane

Comment: @BlueSpud in any case, still no :P - you can either disable the lights when you know you are rendering something outside the room, or use shadow casting.

Comment: @BlueSpud: What I mean is that interior wallstuff and exterior wallstuff are often different stuffs, even if they’re made to look the same. This is to avoid using shadowcasting to solve the problem you’re having, and it also lets you get away with fewer interior (i.e., hidden) vertices.

Comment: @JonPurdy You're better off using front- and back-material properties (by setting the face parameter in `glMaterial` or using the `gl_FrontFacing` shader variable).  Unless there's sufficient spacing between the interior and exterior polygons, you'll get z-fighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, you want the walls of the room to cast a shadow.  That's what you want when you want the exterior part of the object not to be lit.

Shadowing in graphics, is generally a *pretty hard problem*.  There are a lot of good, and a lot of fast, solutions, but not both -- any one solution is going to be a tradeoff between the two.  SIGGRAPH is [full](http://visual-computing.intel-research.net/art/publications/sdsm/) of [all sorts](http://s2012.siggraph.org/attendees/sessions/efficient-real-time-shadows) of [papers](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/papers/deepshadows/) from Really Smart People trying to solve this problem.

If you want something quick and dirty, [shadow mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping) is not terribly difficult (at least the simple kind), but it is imprecise.  You'll see artifacts along the intersections of your object and the walls, for one.  For precision, [stencil shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_shadows) will work, but you'll have hard-edged shadows.

Comment: I've looked into shadows for months now. I've never been much of a book person and Its hard to make of things that are just principles. Do you know of any good tutorials for stencil shadows or volume shadows? I've played with the stencil buffer but I've only been able to make reflections.

Comment: If you've been looking at them for months now, you're probably much further along the "looking for a good tutorial" search than I am.  It's been a long time since I've had to look it up.  Nothing cool ever comes quick or easy :-)

Comment: Eh, what the heck.  This looks superficially pretty good: http://joshbeam.com/articles/stenciled_shadow_volumes_in_opengl/

Comment: I've looked at that in the past. It works fine, it just doesn't really show how to make irregular shapes, it relies on the caster being a cube from what I can see.

Comment: Ah alright.  Well, sometimes you just gotta' bite the bullet, and learn the math.

Comment: But I don't wanna! You're right, most definitely just wish there was someone who had a simple way to do it. *sigh*

Comment: @BlueSpud: Like they say: There's no such thing as a free meal. And when it comes to programming you'll have to bite the math bullet sooner than later. Computer graphics heavily depends on linear algebra, topology and to some degree differential geometry (all the modern graphics algorithms are essentially differential geometry). If you want to animate things and draw nicely curved surfaces some knowledge about calculus is indispensable, too.

Answer (score 1):

One solution here would probably be to author the geometry in a way, that objects don't protrude outside walls (or separate them into inside/outside parts). Then render the interior and exterior with different lights.

You wouldn't have the problem if everything would cast shadows on everything.

If the lights are static, you might want to consider pre-calculating (baking) the lighting (together with shadows). You can do this in many 3D packages, and from a programming perspective this might be the simplest solution.

If you had a general solution for real-time rendering shadows for every light, that would also solve your problem, but that is a challenging task, and it might also not be the optimal thing to do, if you want to maintain good frame-rates.

If you want to learn about real-time shadow rendering, I recommend looking at shadow maps - they are generally the solution used in most games today. Note that for a point light you would need to render the shadow map for 6 sides of a cube-map. For practical purposes you should really consider which lights really need to cast shadows, and make some kind of trade-off.